# how do we compare a localfile and hdfs file for consistency

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

```
    public String getDirs() throws IOException{
        fs=FileSystem.get(conf);
        fs.copyFromLocalFile(new Path("/private/tmp/as"), new Path("/test"));
        LocalFileSystem lfs=LocalFileSystem.getLocal(conf);

//      System.out.println(new LocalFileSystem().ge (conf.getLocalPath("/private/tmp/as")));
        System.out.println("Local Path : "+lfs.getFileChecksum(new Path("/private/tmp/as")));   
        System.out.println("HDFS PATH : "+ fs.getFileChecksum(new Path("/test/as")));
        return "done";
    }
```

Output is

> Local Path : null 
>   HDFS PATH : MD5-of-0MD5-of-512CRC32:a575c5e99b2e08605dc7c6723889519c

Not sure why the checksum is null for local file

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop relies on the FileSystem to have a checksum ready to match against. It does not generate one on-the-fly.

By default, the LocalFileSystem (or the specific implementation used for `file://` paths) does not create/store checksums for all files created through it. You can toggle this behavior via the [FileSystem#setWriteChecksum](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/fs/ChecksumFileSystem.html#setWriteChecksum%28boolean%29) API call, and subsequently retrieving the checksum post-write will then work.